# how to vertically align two tables with horizontal scroll at bottom

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to vertically align two tables with horizontal scroll at bottom.

The following is the HTML code:

```
<div class="cntnr">
<div class="tabtwocntnr">
    <table class="tabtwo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
            <th>Header 10</th>
            <th>Header 11</th>
            <th>Header 12</th>
            <th>Header 13</th>
            <th>Header 14</th>
            <th>Header 15</th>
            <th>Header 16</th>
            <th>Header 17</th>
            <th>Header 18</th>
            <th>Header 19</th>
            <th>Header 20</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
            <th>Header 10</th>
            <th>Header 11</th>
            <th>Header 12</th>
            <th>Header 13</th>
            <th>Header 14</th>
            <th>Header 15</th>
            <th>Header 16</th>
            <th>Header 17</th>
            <th>Header 18</th>
            <th>Header 19</th>
            <th>Header 20</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tabthreecntnr">
    <table class="tabthree">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
            <td>Content 7</td>
            <td>Content 8</td>
            <td>Content 9</td>
            <td>Content 10</td>
            <td>Content 11</td>
            <td>Content 12</td>
            <td>Content 13</td>
            <td>Content 14</td>
            <td>Content 15</td>
            <td>Content 16</td>
            <td>Content 17</td>
            <td>Content 18</td>
            <td>Content 19</td>
            <td>Content 20</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
            <td>Content 4</td>
            <td>Content 5</td>
            <td>Content 6</td>
            <td>Content 7</td>
            <td>Content 8</td>
            <td>Content 9</td>
            <td>Content 10</td>
            <td>Content 11</td>
            <td>Content 12</td>
            <td>Content 13</td>
            <td>Content 14</td>
            <td>Content 15</td>
            <td>Content 16</td>
            <td>Content 17</td>
            <td>Content 18</td>
            <td>Content 19</td>
            <td>Content 20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
   </div>
```

The corresponding css is:

```
.tabtwo,.tabthree{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.tabtwo th, .tabthree td{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.tabthree td{
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.tabtwocntnr,.tabthreecntnr{
    width:100%;

}
    .cntnr{
    overflow-x:auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The fiddle is :
http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/

As we can see in this fiddle the two tables are not aligned properly(with respect to each other).There is also some white space at the right corner of the bottom table. I have tried resolving it by applying table-layout: fixed; to both the tables.

I am unable to achieve the desired result.

Please help me by contributing.

Comment: Why are they split into two tables - they should be part of the same table if the data is tabular otherwise you shouldn't be using tables as it makes to sense to have a th without any corresponding tds - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8H5Ek/5/

Comment: my requirement forces me to split them into two tables

Comment: then you are writing bad web content

Comment: no I dont think so since the kendo framework also provides the component "kendo ui grid" which does the same way as I have done it

You can have a look at http://jsbin.com/IMAyax/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Without giving explicit widths, controlling tables can be very tricky.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/3/**

Add these styles to your css:

```
table { width: 100%; }
th, td { width: 84px; }
```

You have to estimate the width of the `td` carefully.

**Edit**:

Here is another fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/12/**

You can control the content length by using ellipsis. Moreover, you do not need those two inner divs (*tabtwocntnr* and *tabthreecntnr*). You can rid of them.

```
th, td { 
    width: 84px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

try changing `width:100%` to `width:auto` on the `table` css and then see how the content re-sizes the first header cell

Comment: is there any way to make `th` resize according to content??

Comment: I would support the question raised by "NoobEditor"-
is there any way to make th resize according to content??

Comment: normally `white-space: nowrap;` is used to make a cell resize according to content. but in your use-case this will mess up the layout. moreover, if th is resized then the corresponding td will not align!

Comment: @abhitalks : in this case it won't do...`white-space: nowrap;` only trims the white-space, it has no role in dimensions of a tag...

Comment: @NoobEditor: no. `white-space:nowrap` doesn't trim spaces. it prevents wrapping on spaces. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/9/ Look at the bottom table in blue. try changing the content in any td and watch how it expands and contracts as per the content.

Comment: @user2594152: the example you linked to (on jsbin) is using a plugin from kendo. if you look at the css, even there the width of each td/th is fixed at 200px (colgroup). and is controlled by `white-space: nowrap;` That is exactly what i suggested you!

Comment: I agree with you that he is following the approach you mentioned.But is that the only way to achieve it?? Or we can achieve it using any other approach. If so, then how??

Comment: Content-based resizing of tables is just not possible without `white-space: nowrap` (without fixed width). If, you need a fixed width (which you require for your use-case), there is no other option.

Comment: lol...i love these kind of situations...where we have little RnD facility going on SO :)

Comment: can you post your solution once please??

Comment: @user2594152 : i have updated my answer to reflect that. try changing `width:100%` to `width:auto` on the table css and then see how the content re-sizes the first header cell.

Comment: if there is no other way remaining to solve the question apart from providing fixed with to the th and td of tables then yes otherwise no

Answer (score 0):

for `.tabtwo,.tabthree` you have to set `width:100%;` and set the width for parent...add

```
html, body {
    width:100%;/* added */
    height:100%;/* added */
    margin:0;/* added */
    padding:0;/* added */
}
```

then you have to use `colspan` to fix the width of `th`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/2/)

**EDIT**

okay...solution was there in front of eyes...bit of your bad markup played foul....
`thead` and `tbody` is used for marking things in single table...you have used 2 different tables for it, that's why alignment issue is there..

delete this and you are done:

```
 </table>
   </div>
   <div class="tabthreecntnr">
 <table class="tabthree">
```

[**final demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8H5Ek/10/)

Comment: I cannot remove the other table and the div surrounding it as my requirement does not allow me to do it.

Comment: You can have a look at jsbin.com/IMAyax/2/edit
I want to achieve something like this

Comment: then we have a css problem...wait again!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: how is your edit allowing th resize according to content? i mean your first question to me!

Comment: @abhitalks : in **edit**, its a same table with `tbody` and `thead` but original is not allowing ..that's why i asked....i want to know if there is any to allow `width` without `px`...

Comment: @NoobEditor: **no**. your edit still does not allow content based re-sizing. did you try changing any cell's content? the `white-space:nowrap` is the **only** way to do that in tables as I mentioned. did you see the fiddle example i posted?

Comment: @abhitalks : yes...but m trying to find a work around...there might a non-conventional way!!! :)